# Array of NSButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, outlet

I wonder if I can do something like

```
IBOutlet NSButton * aButton[100];
```

It turns out that aButton cannot be seen in the interface builder.

My app has lots of buttons and I want to see if there are way I can use looping to iterate the state of all buttons.

Comment: Your app has a hundred buttons?

Comment: Yes, My app, actually a software on MACOSX, has 48 checkboxes. I just think it's too bulky to define them one by one in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IB doesn't handle arrays. You can add them using a loop in your code instead.

Answer (score 3):

You may find an NSMatrix of NSButtonCells easier to work with, and unlike a C array of NSButtons, you can create one in IB.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use an array as an outlet.  Some options:

- create a NSButton subclass
  that does what you want to do
- walk the view hierarchy at runtime to
  find the buttons

OTOH, if your UI has 100 buttons, you've probably got bigger problems...